# Как доработать данный код?

Tags: javascript

```
function removePreloader(){
  $('.preloader-wrapper').delay(100).fadeOut('slow');
  $('body').addClass('siteloaded');
}

$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  removePreloader()
})
```

Привет есть такой простой код, при загрузке Дома выполянется функция. Как сделать проверку что если DOM грузится больше 2 секунды, выполнить эту функцию?

Comment: `> при загрузке Дома выполянется функция. Как сделать проверку что если DOM грузится больше 2 секунды, выполнить эту функцию?` Что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var loading = true;

setTimeout(function(){
  if( loading ){ removePreloader(); }
}, 2000);

$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  loading = false;
  /* Если этот кусок загрузится быстрее, функция внутри timeout уже не сработает */
  removePreloader();
});


/* Когда начинается выполнение скрипта, первым делом инициализируются функции,
   даже если они находятся в конце */
function removePreloader(){
  $('.preloader-wrapper').delay(100).fadeOut('slow');
  $('body').addClass('siteloaded');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Както так

```
setTimeout(()=>{/* если у body нет класса siteloaded, то добавить его */}, 2000)
```